# Node installation in homebrew vs miniconda

Tags: node.js, miniconda

Hi I'm on MacOS M1 and I noticed that installing nodejs 20.9.0 via homebrew and miniconda3 has some difference in the libs linking

If install via homebrew, I see

```
otool -L $(which node)
/opt/homebrew/bin/node:
        /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.12)
        /opt/homebrew/opt/libuv/lib/libuv.1.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
        /opt/homebrew/opt/brotli/lib/libbrotlidec.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.1.0)
        /opt/homebrew/opt/brotli/lib/libbrotlienc.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.1.0)
        /opt/homebrew/opt/c-ares/lib/libcares.2.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.10.1)
        /opt/homebrew/opt/libnghttp2/lib/libnghttp2.14.dylib (compatibility version 41.0.0, current version 41.0.0)
        /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib/libcrypto.3.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
        /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib/libssl.3.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
        /opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib (compatibility version 73.0.0, current version 73.2.0)
        /opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicuuc.73.dylib (compatibility version 73.0.0, current version 73.2.0)
        /opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicudata.73.dylib (compatibility version 73.0.0, current version 73.2.0)
        /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 2202.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1600.157.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1336.61.1)
```

If installed via miniconda, I see

```
otool -L $(which node)
/Users/me/miniconda3/envs/virtualenv/bin/node:
        @rpath/libnode.115.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1292.0.0)
```

I encountered an error `symbol not found in flat namespace` when using `create-dmg` package with node installed in miniconda3. I did some troubleshooting and I suspect it's because node not linked to `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation` when installed in miniconda

Installing locally via homebrew works fine.

Does anyone has any idea how to solve it? I would still like to use miniconda as my virtual environment.